# Pentaho Issue: Error when connecting two steps

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Currently having issues in Pentaho 9.3 when connecting two steps. In this example, HTTP Client step to Text file output. I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException not sure if this is related to the installation. We are currently using Pentaho in a shared environment and there are already existing jobs using the same HTTP Client steps that are in place and currently running.

I have also the screenshots attached.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcLJj.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu4ts.png)

I have tried checking the Java version and it is currently Java 1.8

Comment: Does it work if you use the Dummy step instead of the Text Output step? Also, review the compatibility table with Java in the Pentaho docs, I don't remember if Java 8 is still compatible with 9.3 or if they fully migrated to Java 11. The docs are available at Hitachi Vantara official website.

Comment: it is not working either. it only occurs when your are trying to connect steps that has options. Example: HTTP Client -> Dummy or Text output step, there will be an option (Main output of step or Error Handling of step)

Comment: However when trying to connect steps that has no option, I can successfully connect them.

Comment: One more thing is, I have also tried it in another laptop. PDI 9.3 with Java 1.8 installed and it is working fine

Comment: In the Text file output, check the fields you are sending, maybe there is a step which is not extracted from the previous step. If the content extracted from the HTTP client step could vary, try adding some "constant" values.